# Save and load a UIScrollView position

Tags: iphone, ios, photoshop, layer

Im creating an app that uses a UIScrollView that scrolls through images and a segmented control that loads a new view and allows a new layer of images (bit like Photoshop layering) - For some reason when I click back on the layer, it remembers the position but creates a new layer.... How can I stop this from happening, so once a layer has been selected and an image chosen, when the user returns it goes to the last loaded position?

Also, as a side thing... I cannot use my gesture recognition or UIAlertView when the UIScrollView is loaded? Does anyone know why?

Here is my code.... And thanks in advance:)

```
- layerControl:(NSInteger)index
{
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger viewCount = 15;
for (int i = 0; i < viewCount; i++) {
    CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
    UIImageView *filterViewOverlay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [filterViewOverlay setImage:[filterManager objectAtIndex:i]];
    [scroll addSubview:filterViewOverlay];
    [filterViewOverlay release];
}
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * viewCount, self.view.frame.size.height);
  [self.view addSubview:scroll];
[scroll release];

switch (index)
{
    case 0: scroll = self.scroll1;
    case 1: scroll = self.scroll2;
    case 2: scroll = self.scroll3;
    case 4: scroll = self.scroll4;
    case 5: scroll = self.scroll5;

}

/* if (scroll == nil)
{
    [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
    NSInteger viewCount = 15;
    for (int i = 0; i < viewCount; i++) {
        CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
        UIImageView *filterViewOverlay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [filterViewOverlay setImage:[filterManager objectAtIndex:i]];
        [scroll addSubview:filterViewOverlay];
        //[filterViewOverlay release];
    }
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * viewCount, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];
    [scroll autorelease]; */


} 
}



//Method to add a filter to the page
- (void)addFilter:(id)sender
{
    UISegmentedControl *filterController = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

[self layerControl:[filterController selectedSegmentIndex]];
}

 - (UIImage*)saveImages
{

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UrbanPhoto##1"];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try saving the value of `UIScrollView.contentOffset` before the user action, and then restoring that value after the action is completed.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I could use 1 scrollView and reinitialise that when for buttons are pressed, if they have previously been initialised, then they are loaded with the previous configuration? Cheers!

Comment: Keep references in an `NSMutableDictionary` or similar. When you need to load one, just check if `NSMutableDictionary objectForKey:` returns `nil` for the key you need. If it does, then initialize a new `UIScrollView`. Otherwise, just use the old one.